# It's possible to use a non-US account with the new iOS SDK 1.0.4 on Production Enviroment

Tags: ios6, paypal

I have problems configuring the new iOS PayPal SDK, when I initialize the enviroment with PayPalEnvironmentProduction I've allways recived a alertview with next message "There was a problem communicating with the PayPal servers".

I think that the problem is because I use a non-US account.

Would you help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but I have configured my environment to be PayPalEnvironmentSandbox and all I get is the PLATFORM error 589009 when trying to use my Swedish account. According to PayPal it should work with a non-US account for testing but not for a Live account.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to be sure that you use the live clientID and recipient email, as the credentials are different for live & sandbox. (Not that this is your problem, but it's good to double check.)

However, be aware that non-US support is still under development.